# Rest API based TCP client using Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, tcpclient

I have tried to create TCP Client with rest api using nodejs and also used net module to establish tcp connection to send/receive data. The main idea is to use this restAPI from browser to load test TCP Connections.

Here in my case there are 2 steps involved while load testing TCP.
1) send initial TCP request which has token for authentication.
2) then send other TCP request to send some data.

The issue is when i try to send 2nd TCP request after authentication. Getting response as invalid session.

Please suggest if i can send TCP request for authentication and using same session/connection while making subsequent requests.

I am new to node js. My Apologize if I have not provided enough details or done some thing invalid.

Initially I have used Packet Sender application and enabled persistent TCP Connection option in it. It worked well as expected but this is for single user and cant use this tool for load testing. Here in this tool with persistent TCP enabled I can see the local port is fixed and not changing upon sending multiple requests but with my node js code i can see the local port is getting changed upon every new request.

I have also used TCP Sampler in Jmeter with reuse Connection option but not working when i send 2nd request after authentication.

```
var Net = require('net');
var express = require("express");
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/api/push', function (req, res) {

var reqBody = req.body.reqBody;

var req = JSON.stringify(reqBody);

const client = new Net.Socket({
        allowHalfOpen: true
    });

client.connect({
    port: req.body.port,
    host: req.body.host
}, function () {

    client.write(req);

});

client.on('data', function (chunk) {

    res.write(chunk.toString());

    //Tried to use client connection information, but didnt worked not sure if i missed something.
    console.log(JSON.stringify(client));

    // Tried commenting below client.end but no luck.
    client.end();

});

client.on('end', function () {
    res.end();

});

client.on('error', function (err) {

    console.log("Error: " + err.message);
    res.write(err.message);
    client.end();

});

});

app.listen(1234, () => {
    console.log("Server running on port 1234");
});
```

1) send restAPI with TCP server host/port and request body for authentication.
2) send another restAPI to use same TCP connection and send data. but it failed for mere

Comment: have you found answer to this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Inspect the behavior and get the cookies details and preserve the same in HTTP cookie manager to reuse the same session for the second request. Just adding http cookie manager also might work. Please check,